# Switch between virtual consoles on virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, console, rhel7

I have a laptop running RHEL 7.  On it, I use Firefox to access the vSphere web client.  In there, I open a web console to a VM where I'm testing a kickstart config.  The kickstart is bombing out, and I get a huge python dump that doesn't help me.  I want to switch between virtual consoles on the VM, but every Google search says to use Ctrl+Alt+Space, then Fn  That just changes consoles on my laptop.  How do I switch between virtual consoles on the VM?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

That's all you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

In VMware 7 Web console, I have used [Alt+Right Arrow] and [Alt+Left Arrow] to switch between different virtual consoles of a guest VM.